# using spring boot and crud how to update list for two class (there are relation between them )in the same time

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, crud

```
@PutMapping("/edit/{id}")
public String updatePatient(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id,
                            @Valid @RequestBody Patient newpatient ) {
     Patient patient = patientRepo.findById(id);

           /**for patient section **/

     patient.setFName(newpatient.getFName());
     patient.setMName(newpatient.getMName());
     Patient updated = patientRepo.save(patient);

     return "updated";
}
```

I want to add for example patient history with its fields by setters and getters. I tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Add those code your tried for _example patient history_

Comment: Please add the code you tried and details on what exactly went wrong, and how

Comment: use cacade.CascadeAll on relation

Comment: check on this https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types

Comment: iam already using cascade all ,but it still doesn't work